# Content shows up two times

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks

I just created a module and I put this in my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <filteredproducts_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="filteredproducts/myblock" name="myblock" template="test.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </filteredproducts_index_index>
</layout>
```

Now for some reason, no mather what block I put there inside my reference name="content" tag. The block is shown twice.

test.phtml:

```
<?php
    echo "test";
?>
```

IndexController.php:

```
<?php
class Brightinsight_FilteredProducts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

The text shown at the page is testtest. 
So the content must be loaded two times for some reason I just can't seem to figure out how.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does your controller code look like (`Filteredproducts_IndexController::indexAction`)? Maybe that can give us some better clues.

Answer (score 1):

Given your layout / controller combination, the only things I can think of that could cause the output to occur twice are:

1. The `page/2columns-left.phtml` template renders the content block twice (or the content block and manually an instance of `filteredproducts/myblock`).
2. There's an event observer than it manually rendering out the additional block.
3. You are injecting your custom phtml file `test.phtml` into the layout elsewhere as well as in that layout file. Perhaps some initial debug code in one of the core layout files.
4. Your block definition extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` but has additional render code in one of the rendering methods that manually renders, but still calls the parent method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was only additional block filled from backend (Admin Panel -> CMS -> Pages -> Content)